# Alter table add field then error whilst using it

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, alter

I am trying to add a field to a table. If I create the table and then call a sp and add the field inside the sp. I cannot use the field in a where clause

1. run part one and part two together:     no error
2. run part one then part two inside sp:   error (dont forget to drop #table when done)
3. run part one then part two:             error (dont forget to drop #table when done)

Example:

```
/*PART 1*/
select 1 as number
into #table
union all 
select 2 as number
/*******/

/*PART 2*/
ALTER TABLE #table ADD rowNo INT IDENTITY(1,1);

select * from #table
where rowNo between 0 and 10

drop table #table
/********/
```

Here is what I mean by run in a stored proc (new to sql fiddle):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/545ff/1

Comment: I'm thinking for a sp you might need to add a `GO` line between the `ALTER` and the `select` statements.

Comment: Can you explain what's wrong with it - appears to work for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8121d/1

Comment: i've updated the question (didn't know sql fiddle existed its superb!)

Comment: @JoeMajsterski just tried that still get error :(

Answer (score 1):

It seems the error is thrown during code compilation. If you run the select (or any other queries that directly reference the new column) inside an exec() command, it works:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/76b8c/1

Comment: thanks i may end up doing this but its not exactly neat the only other solution is select into another #table and the sp can then use the col